# What makes an InGaAs detector more sensitive to infrared light?

Tags: optoelectronics

What makes an InGaAs detector more sensitive to infrared light than visible light, considering that visible light has a higher photon energy?

Comment: why do you say that an IR camera cannot detect visible light?

Comment: @jsotola, thanks for the comments. Check this link https://pdf.directindustry.com/pdf/xenics/bobcat-320-series/54398-666413.html, the QE is extremely low in the VIS range.

Comment: that is a specific camera ... your question asks about IR cameras in general ... your question should really be about the sensor that is used in that camera

Comment: cameras like that are often provided with filters in the optical path to attenuate visible light

Comment: That's an ingaas sensor rather than a more common silicon sensor. Silicon can detect visible and NIR less than about 1000nm. InGaAs goes much further into the IR but doesn't absorb visible very efficiently. If you're really asking what makes a semiconductor sensitive to lower energy photons but not higher, you should edit your question to make that clear.